# What is an infinite set with increment operation called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

What is an infinite set with a unary increment operation (along with the inverse, decrement) called?
For example, the set of integers, $\mathbb{Z}$, along with an increment operation (f: x -> x + 1), without any other operations. The presence of such an operation will make the elements of the set have a strict order (I think).
Is there a name for this particular algebraic structure?

Comment: If one focuses only on the map $x \mapsto x+1$ and specifies a starting value like $0$ or $1,$ I've seen some logicians refer to a "hereditary set." To force the set to be infinite requires some axioms like Peano's.

Comment: This need **not** induce an ordering - consider the disjoint union of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be called a *discrete linear order* in the literature. See [*Decidable Discrete Linear Orders*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274522?seq=1) (1988, M. Moses). According to [these notes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Eweinstei/061005.pdf), a discrete linear order can be defined as a [strict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders) [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) order without endpoints which satisfies a certain *discreteness condition*, namely that every element has an immediate predecessor and an immediate successor in the ordering:

\begin{align}
& \forall x \exists y (x < y \land \neg \exists z (x < z < y)) & \text{($y$ is a successor of $x$)} \\
& \forall x \exists y (y < x \land \neg \exists z (y < z < x)) & \text{($y$ is a predecessor of $x$)}
\end{align}